# How to couple first element of array with every other element in it to obtain a list of tuples?

Tags: scala

I have an array which is the result of a number of chained transformations (do not have a name reference for it). Its contents are:

```
[Item1, val1, val2, val3, val4]
```

How can I obtain in Scala an output such as

```
[(Item1, val1), (Item1, val2), (Item1, val3), (Item1, val4)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is named `arr`:

```
arr.tail.map((arr(0), _))
```

Comment: Not sure how to apply this, the array is the result of a chain of transformations, so I don't have a reference to its name. Sorry I am new to scala and trying to figure this out.

Comment: Then just do `val arr = ... chain ...` and then this? Why not give it a name?

Comment: If you don't want to give it a name, try `splitAt(1) match { case (head, tail) => tail.map((head.head, _)) }` but this is ugly, so better to use the original answer! [However this does work with an empty/short list, which may be beneficial]